# Acceptance of Location tracking app with nsTimer in background in apple market

Tags: iphone, background, geolocation, nstimer

I have created this location tracking app, that uses nstimer in background to fetch location every 4 mins. 
I am wondering if there will be any problem in submitting the app in the market place..
If you know something regarding it, can you please let me know.
Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's relevant to what your app is doing I don't think it will be a problem.
This is from Apple's [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> 4.1 Apps that do not notify and obtain user consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data will be rejected
>
> 4.2 Apps that use location-based APIs for automatic or autonomous control of vehicles, aircraft, or other devices will be rejected
>
> 4.3 Apps that use location-based APIs for dispatch, fleet management, or emergency services will be rejected
>
> 4.4 Location data can only be used when directly relevant to the features and services provided by the app to the user or to support
>   approved advertising uses

But pay attention that if you want your app to keep getting location updates even in background, you need to declare  this in your plist file, otherwise when the app goes to background you won't be able to get location updates.

> **Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks**
>
> Support for some types of background execution must be declared in
>   advance by the app that uses them. An app declares support for a
>   service using its Info.plist file. Add the UIBackgroundModes key to
>   your Info.plist file and set its value to an array containing one or
>
> **location**—The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it
>   is running in the background.

Comment: Thanx for the hints. In the info.plist file such info like, using bg mode has been properly declared. As pointed out in 4.4, location data in my app is collected for the sole purpose of app feature and users will be properly notified about this. So i guess thts clear abt tht. But what about the using nstimer in bg. Might tht be an issue??

Comment: I'm doing the same thing with my current app, every 5 minutes I ask the location manager for a location update and then shut it off. So I very much hope so that it won't be a problem :) From the searches i done, and from Apple docs I couldn't find anything that forbid this, but can't tell you I'm 100% sure because my app is still in development..

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten one app through. You have to make sure that the user is informed exactly as to what is going on. So dialogs have to be very specific and have a privacy policy in place.

4 minutes is a little bit extreme if that's a permanent state of your app.. I don't think Apple would allow that if they found it during app review. Would it not suffice to just have it updated based on movement? ie. the significant location change api?

The app I did this for used significant location change api for background location tracking and then stepped it up to higher frequency tracking if the app was actually open.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Requirement for the app needs tht the location be updated quiet frequently. So significant location change update is not the solution. What I am mostly concerned is that my application uses nsTimer in the background for that purpose. I am wondering if that will be a problem for the app submission.

Comment: Sometime requirements are thought up that do not work in the real world. You should use the `significant location change` method if you are tracking the location in the background, since that will notify you if the user has moved. There is not need to update the location o the user if the user hasen't moved. You way will drain the battery in a couple of hours. This will get you some really bad reviews in the Appstore and as a result of that no one use you app.